# Write to Xml File using Asp-C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm trying to store Some values to an xml file.I've already created an Xml file and trying to overwrite data. The code is given..

```
/*storepassword.cs *//

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

public class StorePassword
{
    public StorePassword()
    {
    }
    public void  store(NewPassword nps)
    {
       XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

       //XmlDoc.Load(@"Password.xml");
       XmlDoc.LoadXml("Password.xml");

       XmlNode root = XmlDoc.DocumentElement;
       XmlNode myNode1 = root.SelectSingleNode("UserName");
       XmlNode myNode2 = root.SelectSingleNode("PassWord");
       myNode1.Value = "sjn";
       myNode2.Value = "sjn123";
       XmlDoc.Save(@"Password.xml");
   }
}

//NewPassword.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class NewPassword
{

    public NewPassword()
    {

    }
    public string username{ get; set; }
    public string Password{ get; set; }
}
```

on button click..

```
NewPassword nps = new NewPassword();
nps.username = TxtUser.Text;
nps.Password = TxtNewPassword.Text;
StorePassword sp=new StorePassword();
sp.store(nps);
```

The existing Xml file contains the following..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ROOT>
  <UserName>abc</UserName>
  <PassWord>123</PassWord>
</ROOT>
```

But it's not working..

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

this error occures..

Ichanged the code as `XmlDoc.Load(@"Password.xml");`

now error changed to

```
Root element is missing.

   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web                  request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it   originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.
```

why this happens?

Comment: LoadXml is for loading an xml document represented as text. You want to use Load instead (as in the commented line)

Comment: Root element is missing
this error occures now

Comment: Means your document is empty. Just do a `new XmlDocument()` then

Comment: Like Simon said, `Load` is the method you should use. Can you post the full error message you get & where you get it? Also, try to take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125810/root-element-is-missing).

Comment: @Sudheesh you xml file is empty..have you checked whether the xml is empty or contain the same format as shown above..check the xml file and the path you are referring to..

Comment: delete <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: I've checked the file and it's not empty.. same error occures even after deleting that line of code

Comment: put `Password.xml` in c:\\ or anywhere and then access it like `xyz.Load("c:\\Password.xml");`

Answer (score 1):

Try using XML Serialization:

```
public static partial class ObjectXMLSerializer<T> where T : class
{
            private static void SaveToDocumentFormat(T serializableObject, System.Type[] extraTypes, string path, IsolatedStorageFile isolatedStorageFolder)
            {
                using (TextWriter textWriter = CreateTextWriter(isolatedStorageFolder, path))
                {
                    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = CreateXmlSerializer(extraTypes);

                    //Cuong: set name space to null
                    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                    ns.Add("", "");
                    xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, serializableObject, ns);
                }
            }
            public static void Save(T serializableObject, string path)
            {
                    SaveToDocumentFormat(serializableObject, null, path, null);
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you load your Xml you need to use Server.MapPath . `XmlDoc.LoadXml(Server.MapPath("Password.xml"));`

Answer (score 0):

delete

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ROOT>
  <UserName>abc</UserName>
  <PassWord>123</PassWord>
</ROOT>
```

I do not know why it works but we do that all the time in our code. And yes you should be using [XmlDocument.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx) not [XmlDocument.LoadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx)