# While binding Treeview control to xmldatasource, "Exception:Root element is missing " is occured

Tags: asp.net, xml, treeview, xmldatasource

aspx file:

```
  <div>
    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" 
        ShowCheckBoxes="All" ShowLines="True">
    </asp:TreeView>
    <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/Details.xml">
    </asp:XmlDataSource>
  </div>
```

Deatails.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <Root>
 <Collection Name="Server 1">
  <Box>MB1</Box>
  <Box>MB2</Box>
  <Box>MB3</Box>
  <Box>MB4</Box>
  <Box>MB5</Box>
  </Collection>
 </Root>
```

Stack Trace:

```
 [XmlException: Root element is missing.]
 System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) +76
 System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowWithoutLineInfo(String res) +61
 System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent() +3981048
 System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() +151
 System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace) +58
 System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc) +20
 System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace) +129
 System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader) +108
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlDataSource.PopulateXmlDocument(XmlDocument document, CacheDependency& dataCacheDependency, CacheDependency& transformCacheDependency) +306
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlDataSource.GetXmlDocument() +153
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlHierarchicalDataSourceView.Select() +17
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.DataBindNode(TreeNode node) +125
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.PerformDataBinding() +120
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +85
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +73
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.DataBind() +4
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +82
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +22
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +36
 System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +80
 System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
 System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +842
```

While loading the page the exception is thrown, I tried to validate the xml file & its valid according to w3cshools validator. What things do cause this exception. Correct me where I went wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your treeview code once like below

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
<DataBindings>  
 <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Collection" TextField="Name" />  
  <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Box" TextField="Name" />  

 </DataBindings> 
</asp:TreeView>
```

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
 <Collection Name="Server 1">
  <Box Name="MB1"></Box>
  <Box Name="MB2"></Box>
  <Box Name="MB3"></Box>
  <Box Name="MB4"></Box>
 </Collection>
```

[TreeView Example](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.in/2008/10/treeview-example-how-to-use-treeview.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But still the same exception is thorwn.

Comment: Are you able to access the XML file without any issues?

Comment: I updated my answer, once try with my treeview code and sample XML file. Check this answer also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125810/root-element-is-missing/10125981#10125981

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
   <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/Details.xml">
   </asp:XmlDataSource>
   <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" 
    ShowCheckBoxes="All" ShowLines="True">
      <DataBindings>  
          <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Collection" TextField="Name" />  
          <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Box" TextField="Name" />  
     </DataBindings> 
  </asp:TreeView>
</div>
```

I have just changed the place of xmldatasource, & its working now.