# Xml serializing and deserializing with memory stream

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm getting an error with the following code where it can't find a root element when it tries to deserialize the code:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: There is an error in XML document (0, 0).
>   Inner exception: {"Root element is missing."}

It seems straightforward enough code, but googling and searching SO on the issue hasn't yielded any clear answers--only similar issues that are nonetheless that the answer don't help... or I'm misunderstanding something.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestSerialize()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(testObject.GetType());
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.Serialize(memStream, testObject);

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(testObject.GetType());
        TestObject testObj = ((TestObject)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(memStream));
        assert(testObject == testObj);
    }

public class TestObject
{
    public int IntProp { get; set; }
    public string StringProp { get; set; }
}
```

The alleged duplicate question at [Root element is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125810/root-element-is-missing) uses XMLDocument objects and has a different correct answer.

Comment: try setting the memorystreem location to zero after serializing. or use a new memorystream

Comment: *"I'm getting an error"*... **what** error? Please be specific.

Comment: "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: There is an error in XML document (0, 0)."

Comment: details: {"There is an error in XML document (0, 0)."}  inner exception: {"Root element is missing."}

Comment: Good. Now edit your question and add that information to it.

Comment: @AndyIsbell If you look at the other question, one of the other upvoted answer on it has exactly the same answer.  So voting to leave closed.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf But the answer accepted to that question, and the question itself, are different.  If someone is looking to find the answer to my issue they won't be searching the other asker's issue...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After serialization, the MemoryStream's position is > 0. You need to reset it before reading from it.

```
memStream.Position = 0;
```

Or...

```
memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for helping--I wouldn't have thought that the stream's state was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to reset the postition of your MemoryStream as after having serialized your XML to it the position will be at the end.

```
memStream.Position = 0;
XmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(testObject.GetType());
TestObject testObj = ((TestObject)xmlSerialzer.Deserialize(memStream));
```

Comment: Thanks, I just marked the first to answer correctly but this helped.