# System.Xml.XmlException:Root element is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have a REST Api that returns json as HttpResponseMessage.
When I run it in locallhost in my computer everything is ok and I get the json result.
But when I hosted it on the IIS server in another system I get this error:

```
{
   "Message": "An error has occurred.",

   "ExceptionMessage": "Root element is missing.",

   "ExceptionType": "System.Xml.XmlException",

   "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.

<InvokeActionWithExceptionFilters>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()"
}
```

I use SoapUI as Web Service Testing Tools

return result code block:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(XML_Result);
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);


response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StringContent(jsonText, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
// return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response, Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
return response;
```

edited: error occurred when calling LoadXml and its parameter  comes from another service that I calling it here .
in this line of code

```
          doc.LoadXml(XML_Result);
```

Comment: Better show how you get the `XML_Result` value.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderPetrov , its comes from another service that I call it here

Comment: You can to look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125810/root-element-is-missing

Comment: I thought you get the shown error exactly when calling the `doc.LoadXml` method. Is that so?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Maybe,But it works correctly locally on my system.

Comment: Where exactly is the error thrown?

Comment: tanx @AlexanderPetrov, XML_Result returns an empty string.it is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error occurred when calling LoadXml method.
In doc.LoadXml(XML_Result) XML_Result was returning an empty string.
it is solved when it was not empty.